# Verify that T is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> Define
>   $$ T\pmatrix  { \begin {bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix} }=\begin {bmatrix} x_1+x_3 \\ x_2+x_3 \end{bmatrix}$$
>   Verify that T is a linear transformation

I know that this is not the best format, and I understand if you are frustrated, but if you can resist, please don't post a comment just telling me that I should write my questions better.

**I have just a few questions:** Since there are three inputs, shouldn't there be three outputs as well? Is there a zero in there somewhere? Like, should I read it like this: T(x1, x2, x3) = (x1 + x2, 0, x2 + x3), where the zero is in the middle? How is it supposed to be read?

Comment: Why do you think 3 inputs must mean 3 outputs?  You can define a function from any set to any set. Your function is currently defined to take as input a 3 dimensional vector and give as output a 2 dimensional vector. We can also define a function that takes in a 5 dimensional vector and spits out a 1 dimensional vector (i.e., a number). Here is an example. Define $T(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) = x_1$. $T$ in this example takes the 5D vector in, and spits out just the first component.

Comment: **Hint:** Show that $T$ is a matrix transformation (i.e., $T(X)=AX$ for some $A\in M_{2\times 3}(\Bbb R)$) which are linear.

Comment: @wannabemathmajor The person who asked can vote for one or more answers and mark one as "accepted". Please visit https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function is a linear transformation if

$T(\mathbf x + \mathbf y) = T(\mathbf x) + T(\mathbf y)$ and $T(a\mathbf x) = aT(\mathbf x)$

Does this satisfy those two rules?

As for your other question, why can't a function have a different codomain from its domain?

Isn't $f(x,y) = x+y$ a valid function (and a linear map).

Going the other way, $f(t) = (t, 2t, 3t)$ is also a linear map.

Comment: Ok, ok. I think I get it. I just needed some clarifications. So, for example, if I wanted to show the scalar multiplication property, this is what I'm thinking:

After letting x1 = u1, u2, u3,
T(cx1) = T(c(u1, u2, u3))
= T(cu1, cu2, cu3)
= (cu1 + cu3, cu2 + cu3)
= c(u1 + u3, u2 + u3)
= cT(x1)
How does that look?

Comment: $\mathbf x = (x_1,x_2,x_3), \mathbf y = (y_1,y_2,y_3)\\T(\mathbf x+\mathbf y) = (x_1 + y_1 + x_3+y_3, x_2 + y_2 + x_3 + y_3) = (x_1 + x_3, x_2+x_3) + (y_1+y_3, y_2+y_3)\\T(a\mathbf x) = (ax_1 + ax_3, ax_2 + ax_3) = a(x_1 + x_3, x_2+x_3)$

Answer (score 0):

No, your function $T$ takes inputs from $\mathbb{R}^3$ and has outputs in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that
$$
T\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 
\end{bmatrix} \right) 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 + x_3 \\
x_2 + x_3 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1  \\
x_2  \\
x_3 
\end{bmatrix},
$$
and recall that every matrix transformation is a linear transformation.

Answer (score -1):

$$T (1,2,3)=(4,5)$$

the image of a triplet is  a couple.